# corrupting xml file via transferring ftp

Tags: ftp, mobile-website

I am transferring different xml files via ftp and it's working fine.

But one specific 90kb xml file getting corrupted during tranfer with ftp. Getting corrupted file with 6kb.

Comment: Make sure you are transferring text files as text and not binary.

Comment: What program(s) are you using? What operating system(s)?

Comment: @Oded But other xml files transferring properly getting problem with one specific file.

Comment: Have you been able to determine the differences between "good" and "bad" files? Or _where_ the corruption occurs in the "bad" ones?

Comment: @Oded My all xml files are good. But after transferred xml files with ftp. I got one specific file corrupted or bad. It's showing binary or something differenct characters after tranferred. Other files got proper.

Comment: And, what makes this file/character special? Could it be the only one that isn't ASCII?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using sprint 3G card for net connection. 
I have changed settings of the card. 
I turned off bytemobile optimization.
And it worked like a charm ! 
VOILA !

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that if it's a Unicode file, you have to set to binary (not text, which is the usual default).

**edit**

If you tell us what program you are using (in Ubuntu) to do the ftp, someone here will be able to tell you how to test this possibility.

It's also possible that the program has a bug (I've seen this happen with a popular Usenet reader: only once in a while it would fail, depending on the exact size of a segment).

Comment: @krunal shah: That has nothing to do with it. How are you using ftp? As command-line tool? Or using some GUI?

Comment: @krunal shah: so, does typing `binary<ENTER>` before transferring the files work?